# JQuery future element | .on()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, element, future

```
$.get(DL+"a=ts&q="+Q,function(data){
    $('.load').html(data);
});
```

The data returned from $.get is loaded into the .load class.
There are two portions of the data returned.
The first being, a Nth number of numbers in a single UL.

```
<ul><li class="num id0"...
```

The second, a Nth number of UL(s) with a class of id0 - Nth number.

```
<ul class="list id0"...
```

Once the data has been loaded in to class .load,

```
$(document).on('click','.num',function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('class');
    ID = ID.split(' ');
    ID = ID[1];
    alert(ID);
    $('.list').css('display','none');
    $('.list .'+ID).css('display','inherit');
});
```

An alert with the correct ID is alerted.
However, the .list .idX is not made visible.

I am guessing it is b/c it is not available to the DOM.
So, my question, either how do I make it available, or how do I use .on('not click','.list',function().. to do what I need - or what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Your `split()` call should be `ID = something.split(' ')`.

Comment: This one `$('.list .'+ID).css('display','inherit');` is weird. Why the second dot?

Comment: Instead of setting `display` CSS, why not use `.hide()` and `.show()`?

Comment: @barmar you are right that is just a typo.
ID = ID.split(' '); I will make the edit.

Comment: @entiendoNull: Otherwise the selector would be `.list ID0` instead of `.list .ID0`.

Comment: @entiendoNULL the second dot denotes the second class of the UL class name. <ul class="list id0"> there are two classes..

Comment: Well.. you can use the second class as your selector.. `$('.'+ ID)` should be fine as a selector. No need to use the two classes.

Comment: @entiendoNULL not if other classes on your page are the same.
EX. class="num id0" and class="list id0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** be using the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

```
$('.list.'+ID)
//     ^^ no space
```

This will select all elements with class `list` **and** class `<whatever-ID-refers-to>`, instead of selecting all element with class `<whatever-ID-refers-to>` who are descendants of `.list`.

---

I also recommend to not encode the list IDs in CSS classes, use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: data-* attributes on non html5 pages will not validate according to w3c standards. Right?

Comment: What version of HTML4 your page is in is determined by the DOCTYPE header. And the recommend DOCTYPE to use is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, without any version. So I don't see a problem with using `data-*` attributes.

Comment: I don't see a problem either, I am just not overly familiar with the data attributes. I guess it is time to adjust to the times.. I will replace my DOCTYPE with <!DOCTYPE html>. Thanks for the suggestion.